# How to prevent all code from being parallelized when using MPI library?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi

When I use `mpirun` with the `-np` flag to run a parallel program, it seems that all the processes will start their execution at the beginning of `main`.

For example, for the basic MPI program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);
    printf("From processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

It will print `Hello, World!` multiple times, not as I expected. How can I let the `Hello, World!` (sequential part) execute only once? Maybe I should add some limitations to solve this problem, like using `if (rank == 0)`. But this is a very simple example. I have a really big MPI project! I want only one computing-intensive part to run on multiple compute nodes in parallel and all the rest parts run sequentially. So is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: *So is there any other way to solve this problem?* The solution you outline, that is having code inside `if (rank==0) ... endif` is pretty much the standard solution.  When it comes to your really big project you're likely to find that you (a) grab 2^n processors (b) use one of them for about 1/10^m of your total execution time to set things up (c) use them all for most of the rest of the total execution time and (d) use one of them for about 1/10^m of your total execution time to finalise everything.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your comments.